# What is the Code::Blocks project directory tree scheme?

Tags: codeblocks

If I add a source file to a Code::Blocks project via File>-New->Class... ;
It will put a .h file in Headers/include and a new .cpp file in Sources/src.  I don't understand the reason for the subdirectories under **Headers** and **Sources**. Are there files that would go under Headers and Sources but not in the **include** or **src** directories ?

[image: Code::Blocks project files tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code::Blocks project view classifies files as "Sources" and "Headers".
This is just a *logical* classification that is supposed to be helpful: when you create a project you don't 
actually get directories called `Sources` and `Headers` in the project
directory.

But when you create a class, `MyClass`, the source `.cpp` file and the header
`.h` must physically reside somewhere, and by default Code::Blocks saves
`MyClass.h` in a directory called `include` and `MyClass.cpp` in a directory
called `src`, both under the project directory. Then `include/MyClass.h`
appears under **Headers** and `src/MyClass.cpp` appears under **Sources**

This is a reasonable and conventional default for any simple project. If you
want your files organized in some different way, then you can specify
the directories in which the `.h` and `.cpp` will be saved in the
**Create new class** dialog. You can specify that they will be saved
in the *same* directory, say `UserInterface`; then `UserInterface/SomeClass.h`
will appear under `Headers` and `UserInterface/SomeClass.cpp` will appear under
**Sources**.

You can create whatever subdirectory organization makes sense for your
project's structure - or none. But the source files will show up in the
**Sources** tree and the headers will show up **Headers** tree.